# ACS 723 Current Sensor

Tags: sensor

I used an ACS 723 current sensor to measure a very small current. The output of the current sensor gets converted into a proportional voltage.

I have attached the output of the current sensor. Could somebody tell me the formula or a way to convert this voltage into current?

[image]

Comment: The datasheet specifies something like 100~400mV/A, depends on your model.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome. Have a great new year.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You start with the [datasheet.](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs723-datasheet.ashx)

For each specific module, there is a table that gives you a "Zero Current Output Voltage," and a "Sensitivity."

[image]

Subtract the zero current voltage from your measured voltage then divide by the sensitivity to get current.

Assuming a Vcc of 5V and that you are are using the "xLLCTR-5AB" model (from the example table,) then your measured current (as shown in your example) would be around \$\frac{2.39V-2.5V} {400} = -0.275 amperes.\$

---

There are more items in the datasheet that will help you get better values (expected voltage offset errors, linearity errors, etc.) but the method above will give you a starting point.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will follow this and learn more.